# Tikz rectangle shaped arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have a problem with the placement of labels on "rectangle shaped" arrows. I would like to place the labels middle and most right or left on the most right and left arrows respectively. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!!

**My code**

```
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\matrix(cd)[matrix of math nodes,
  row sep=2.6em, column sep=2cm, 
  text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]{
  F_0a & F_0b \\ 
  F_1a & F_1b \\ 
  F_2a & F_2b \\
}; 
\draw[->] (cd-1-1) edge node[label=above:$F_0f$] (U) {} (cd-1-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-2-1) edge node[label=above:$F_1f$] (V) {} (cd-2-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-3-1) edge node[label=below:$F_2f$] (W) {} (cd-3-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-1-1) edge node[label=left:$t_a$ ] (U) {} (cd-2-1); 
\draw[->] (cd-2-1) edge node[label=left:$t'_a$] (V) {} (cd-3-1); 
\draw[->] (cd-1-2) edge node[label=right:$t_b$ ] (W) {} (cd-2-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-2-2) edge node[label=right:$t'_b$] (U) {} (cd-3-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-1-1.west) -| ++(-.5,0) node[label=left :$(t'\circ t)_a$] {} |- (cd-3-1.west); 
\draw[->] (cd-1-2.east) -| ++(.5,0)  node[label=right:$(t'\circ t)_b$] {} |- (cd-3-2.east); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
```

Comment: Are you using the `position` library of `TikZ` in the preamble?

Comment: It seems I am not, how should the preamble looks like in your opinion?

Comment: Thaks!! That worked perfect!! Nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick solution is to place the nodes using the matrix entries as reference points instead of placing them along the paths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\matrix(cd)[matrix of math nodes,
  row sep=2.6em, column sep=2cm, 
  text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]{
  F_0a & F_0b \\ 
  F_1a & F_1b \\ 
  F_2a & F_2b \\
}; 
\draw[->] (cd-1-1) edge node[label=above:$F_0f$] (U) {} (cd-1-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-2-1) edge node[label=above:$F_1f$] (V) {} (cd-2-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-3-1) edge node[label=below:$F_2f$] (W) {} (cd-3-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-1-1) edge node[label=left:$t_a$ ] (U) {} (cd-2-1); 
\draw[->] (cd-2-1) edge node[label=left:$t'_a$] (V) {} (cd-3-1); 
\draw[->] (cd-1-2) edge node[label=right:$t_b$ ] (W) {} (cd-2-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-2-2) edge node[label=right:$t'_b$] (U) {} (cd-3-2); 
\draw[->] (cd-1-1.west) -| ++(-.5,0) |- (cd-3-1.west); 
\draw[->] (cd-1-2.east) -| ++(.5,0) |- (cd-3-2.east);
\node[anchor=east,xshift=-16pt] at (cd-2-1.west) {$(t'\circ t)_a$}; \node[anchor=west,xshift=16pt] at (cd-2-2.east) {$(t'\circ t)_b$}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

[image]